# HTML5 Data-block JSON

Tags: jquery, html

Okay so this code:

```
<div class="summary-block" data-block-json="{"pageSize":4,"acceptTypes":["gallery","blog","projects","calendar"]}">
```

I'm trying to use some jQuery to accomplish something like this:

```
$(".summary-block").data('block', 'pageSize').each(function() {

  $('.summary-item').wrap('<div class="col sqs-col-3 span-3"></div>');
  $('.col > .summary-item').wrap('<div class="newSummary"></div>');

});
```

Now the code works 100%, but not 100% in terms of what I'm trying to ask it. How can I make it so its like:

```
$(".summary-block").data('block', 'pageSize':4).each(function() {

  $('.summary-item').wrap('<div class="col sqs-col-3 span-3"></div>');
  $('.col > .summary-item').wrap('<div class="newSummary"></div>');

});
```

Notice the :4 this must be included somehow in my code. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't filter the elements, you are only setting new `data` attributes, not selecting the elements that have specific `data` attributes, also in your `each` function context you should use `this` which refers to the current element not `$('.summary-item')` and you should code `data('block-json')`, not `data('block')`.  You can use `filter` method.

```
<div class="summary-block" data-block-json='{"pageSize":4,"acceptTypes":["gallery","blog","projects","calendar"]}'>...</div>
```

```
var $elems = $('.summary-block').filter(function(){
    return $(this).data('block-json').pageSize === 4
})

$elems.each(function(){
    $('.summary-item', this).wrap('<div class="col sqs-col-3 span-3"></div>');
    // or $(this).find('.summary-item')....
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xw2vN/

Comment: That works, but not 100%. It wraps .summary-block I need it to wrap around .summary-item which is located inside the div class .summary-block

Comment: @Nick You can use selector context or `find` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".summary-block").data('block', 'pageSize').where('pagesize' , 4 ).each(function() {
```